# One unity instance, two unity windows?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I run my application I want Unity to open two windows. The windows will have different cameras but both will view the same world.

Is such a thing possible? (I haven't been able to find any evidence to suggest so)

I know I could achieve this with two unity instances but I need one.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/383983/multi-window-applications-in-unity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a recent update to Unity added support for multiple Displays, which do what you're describing. You can read about them [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unity has no built-in support for that. You'll have to design around it or develop something on your own.

I have heard of some people attempting workarounds with multiple processes which communicate via networking or IPC. You could potentially create a separate launcher application to control that.

Comment: Unity 5.1's (multiplayer) networking components should be able to get you there as well I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to have two different physical windows, but just side-by-side views of different cameras, you can adjust the viewport rect.

[image]

Change the position as well as width & height to render cameras side by side or however you'd like.

For a bare bones demo of this, you can get a sample project using Git at https://github.com/bkevelham/multicamerademo.git

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to create another Unity Project and open it with the first one ! after use Network Server (multiplayer component) to start a communication between windows.